# Return string from web2py CRYPT() function

Tags: authentication, encryption, web2py

I am trying to update my auth_user table with

```
hash = CRYPT()(password)[0]
db(query).update(password=str(hash))
```

I keep getting a TypeError: character mapping must return integer, None or unicode, which is odd because I did the same thing in another function and got no errors.
I am trying to understand what I am doing wrong here

Comment: add `type(hash) output`

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry can you be more specific

Comment: it prints <class 'gluon.validators.LazyCrypt'>, which does have __str__ and __repr__, which in the terminal prints exactly what i want when i call str(hash). But in my code it gives an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where does the password come from? Looks like it might be a unicode string. You might try

```
hash = CRYPT()(password.encode('utf8'))[0]
```